# Replace Values between two Data.Frame using Functions

Tags: r, logic

I M new to the programming world and need to find a ways for the following logic to be done in R
I have a data.frame contains 4 variables as

```
df_1

Item     Var1   Var2    Var3
111         2   3   4
222         6   2   8
333         7   1   4
444         3   2   7
```

and so on. I have something 1300 items like this. 
What i need to do is to create a loop to replace the values with another data.frame df_2 having average value as Avg_values of same item codes

```
df_2
Item    Avg_Value
111     3
222     2
333     7
444     5
```

However, It should replace only those values from var1, var2, var3 which are more than Avg_values of df_2. and if it is less then the Avg_values then it should remains the same
I tried creating a function and used for loop and Replace command  to change the values but its not working. Can someone please help in this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should we take `Item` into consideration? if we have to, then:

```
t(apply(merge(df1,df2),1,function(x)c(x[1],replace(y<-x[-1],y>=x[5],x[5]))))
 Item Var1 Var2 Var3 Avg_Value
[1,]  111    2    3    3         3
[2,]  222    2    2    2         2
[3,]  333    7    1    4         7
[4,]  444    3    2    5         5
```

You can then remove the last column if you want to: